# How do I send search result back to client side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm making a web app that uses Spotify API now. I'd like to get a search keyword from client side and send its search result back to the client side. I'm making a post request with the search keyword to "http://localhost:4000/search_result" and send the result back to "http://localhost:4000/api" and then fetch the data. I get a 404 for the fetch call when I look into Network on the Chrome dev tool. 
And I'd also like to know if there's way to make use of the search keyword from the post request for a get request in server.js.

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SingerCard from "./SingerCard";
import axios from "axios";

export class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      keyword: "",
      artists: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:4000/search_result",
        {
          keyword: this.state.keyword,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            // Accept: "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/api")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((artists) => {
        this.setState({ artists });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="search">Search an artist: </label>
          <span>
            <input
              type="search"
              value={this.state.keyword}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="keyword"
            />

            <button type="submit" value="Submit">
              Search
            </button>
          </span>
        </form>
        <br />

        <div className="container">
          {this.state.artists.map((elem) => (
            <SingerCard
              images={elem.images}
              name={elem.name}
              artists={this.state.artists}
            />
          ))}
          {console.log("Arists are: " + this.state.artists)}
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const port = 4000 || process.env.PORT;
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Create the api object with the credentials
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
});

// Retrieve an access token.
spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant().then(
  function (data) {
    console.log("The access token expires in " + data.body["expires_in"]);
    console.log("The access token is " + data.body["access_token"]);

    // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body["access_token"]);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log("Something went wrong when retrieving an access token", err);
  }
);

app.post("/search_result", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.keyword);
  spotifyApi.searchArtists(req.body.keyword).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.body);
    var search_res = data.body.artists.items;

    app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
      res.json(search_res);
      res.end();
    });

    res.end();
  }),
    function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    };
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`It's running on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server side routes should be configured once, not on the fly. When you call `app.post` and `app.get` you are configuring a route and providing a callback that will be used every time a request comes in that matches that route. In your code, you create a post route, and then inside the handler you create a get route. Don't do that.

HTTP Servers are meant to be stateless. This means each request (post, get) know nothing about one another. If you want to share information between, you do it via a database (in-memory, redis, nosql, sql, etc...), where each route is using only the parameters passed to it.

For example, the POST route creates an id for the search results. The POST route returns this id. The GET route when called, should receive this same id and look up the results. Of course, this is only necessary for really long processes, typically job queues. For your specific case, you only need one route.

```
app.post("search_result", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.keyword);
  spotifyApi
    .searchArtists(req.body.keyword)
    .then(
      function(data) {
        console.log(data.body);
        var search_res = data.body.artists.items;

        res.json(search_res);
        res.end();
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    );
});
```

And don't forget to remove your `componentDidMount` code since you only need to call the POST route.

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:4000/search_result",
        {
          keyword: this.state.keyword,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            // Accept: "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ artists });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```